# Bib files in Russian

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, russian

Does .bib file work with russian language?
I mean I can use with \cite{} command any english book parameters written in

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX{} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}
```

But with russian book parameters these code doesn't work. How can I make .bib workable on Russian language?

Comment: the best would be to switch to biblatex + biber, they can handle utf8 bib files without problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, are you talking about this :  %Библиография
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{texbook}
В.А. Иванов Математические основы теории оптимального и логического управления: учеб.пособие /В.А. Иванов , В.С. Медведев, Москва, Изд-во МГТУ им.Баумана, 2011 -599 стр. 

\bibitem{lamport94}


\end{thebibliography}

Comment: I just found this library : \usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}  will try if it work with russian letters in .bib file...

Comment: Oh... It works without number of the book as it required for the bibliography. Using this -> \usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}  I just get the caption in citation, like [ivanov:2011]. It is instead of number of the book and I put this capture in .bib like @book{ivanov:2011,
  author = {В.А. Иванов},
  year = {2011},
  title = {Математические основы теории оптимального и логического управления: учебное пособие / В.А. Иванов, В.С. Медведев},
  publisher = {МГТУ им.Баумана},
  }